# Winter Hats promotion

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

As 2013 comes to a close, Stack Exchange is offering [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) a chance to participate in their [Winter Hats](http://winterba.sh/) event to finish out the year with a little bit of fun.   [Winter Hats](http://winterba.sh/) are offered for participating in Stack Exchange sites from 16 December 2013 until 3 January 2014.

If you are awarded a hat, you have the option of modifying your gravitar to "wear" the hat (graphically) in your icon during the event.  The gravitar modification is not permanent, and can be removed any time you like.

Users discover hats by using [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) in special ways, such as voting, posting on meta, improving posts with valid edits, and chatting. The promotion includes certain non-hat items such as glasses, headphones, bowties, and masks. Hat progress is trackable at the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) landing page, which includes definitions and criteria.  Several hats are secret and only findable by the most diligent users.

[hats promotional leaderboard http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/promos/winter-bash/3.jpg](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/promos/winter-bash/3.jpg)

[Winter Hats](http://winterba.sh/) are optional, and Stack Exchange sites are not required to participate.  However, Stack Exchange needs to know whether [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) would like [Winter Hats](http://winterba.sh/).  Please vote up the *answer* which indicates your interest in the hats event.  Votes must be registered by 1 December 2013 to count.

UPDATE:

We will have hats in 2013.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes**, we want to participate in the [Winter Hats](http://winterba.sh/) promotion.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, we don't want to participate in the [Winter Hats](http://winterba.sh/) promotion.