# Network Engineering Question Competition (12/16/2013 - 1/3/2014)

Tags: discussion

To go along with Stack Exchange's [Winter Hats promotion](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/266/775), the moderators of [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) are offering another bonus... literally.

We're opening a competition with a prize of 250 bonus reputation points for the person who asks the *best questions* between 16 December 2013 until 3 January 2014. The competition is only open to users with less than or equal to 1000 total reputation on the [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) site (as of the day you sign up).

#### How do I start?

1. It's really simple. Add an answer below with your name, and we will start tracking your question scores posted between 16 December 2013 until 3 January 2014. The moderator team will keep the scores updated in this post from time to time.  NOTE: To meet the minimum answer length requirements, please include your name and a bare hyperlink to your NE user profile.
2. Ask questions. However, the rules of the site have not changed; we still need questions to be specific and on-topic. Please see the [Help Center](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic/) for what is on-topic here.

#### How are scores computed?

1. We build a "Composite Q&A score" by adding the number of upvotes on the question, the number of upvotes on the accepted answer, and 1 additional point for every 500 question views. Then take the top four "Composite Q&A scores" and average them. The person with the highest average "Composite Q&A scores" wins the 250 point bonus.
2. Downvotes *do not* count against your Composite Q&A score to discourage competitive downvoting between participants.
3. Only questions with an *accepted answer* will qualify toward winning the bonus.

#### What else should I be aware of?

1. We will monitor for various forms of cheating; it will not be tolerated. If you see something bad happening, please raise a flag to the moderator team.
2. We will award the bonus sometime just before midnight (GMT) on 3 January 2014.
3. Any questions / clarifications about the contest itself should be posted on the [meta question](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/276/775).

---

#### Eligible Questions (Last Update: 23 Dec 2013 @ 6am Central Time - US)

<kbd>Name</kbd>              
<kbd>Q-Score</kbd>
<kbd>A-Score</kbd>
<kbd>View Pts</kbd>   
<kbd>QA Score</kbd>
<kbd>Question</kbd>

<kbd>[Will Dennis](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/85/will-dennis)</kbd>      
            <kbd>3</kbd>
            <kbd>5</kbd>
              <kbd>0</kbd>
              <kbd>4</kbd>
<kbd>[Are the SFP/SFP+ int's on WS-X45-SUP7-E autosensing?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5538/775)</kbd>

<kbd>[MattE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/109/matte)</kbd>               
            <kbd>3</kbd>
            <kbd>3</kbd>
              <kbd>0</kbd>
              <kbd>3</kbd>
<kbd>[What is most effective placement for firewall devices?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5525/775)</kbd>

<kbd>[MattE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/109/matte)</kbd>               
            <kbd>4</kbd>
            <kbd>7</kbd>
              <kbd>0</kbd>
           <kbd>5.5</kbd>
<kbd>[What is the expected behaviour of the ARP cache?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5537/775)</kbd>

<kbd>[MattE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/109/matte)</kbd>               
            <kbd>5</kbd>
            <kbd>5</kbd>
              <kbd>0</kbd>
              <kbd>5</kbd>
<kbd>[Factors that determine compatibility of SFPs...?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/5556/775)</kbd>

#### Leaderboard

1. [MattE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/109/matte) `(3 + 5 + 5.5 + 0) / 4 =` **3.375**
2. [Will Dennis](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/85/will-dennis) `(4 + 0 + 0 + 0) / 4 =` **1.000**
3. [Steven Craven](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1911/stephen-craven) `(0 + 0 + 0 + 0) / 4 =` **0.000** (No questions asked after 16 Dec)
4. [THE DOCTOR](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1453/the-doctor) `(0 + 0 + 0 + 0) / 4 =` **0.000** (No questions asked after 16 Dec)

---

NOTE: Apologies for the goofy formatting, but *[Stack Exchange has no native support for html tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/160519)*

Comment: For clarity for other readers: Mike will put the 250 point bonus on *this* main-site question, and then he'll accept the winner's answer below thus gifting them their bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt Earp (Implementation Manager @ vodafone uk)

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/109/matte

Comment: We've got about an hour left, but MattE basically has an unbreakable lead on the other candidates... Congratulations Matt!  I have to wait 24 hours before the award, so you should see your points sometime over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks Mike! 

Answer (score 3):

Will Dennis, Sr Network Systems Admin., NEC Laboratories America
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/85/will-dennis

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for signing up.  The competition starts on Dec 16th... get your questions ready :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Stephen Craven](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1911/stephen-craven).

Answer (score 3):

THE DOCTOR, Time Lord, TARDIS

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1453/the-doctor